# Visual Studio project not running when logging with another user account

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio project made by a collegue wenn he was logged in under his own microsoft account.
Now I want to run the project on the same PC but when logged under my own user account.
But I get the following error.

[image]

Unfortunately the error description is in french even with VS set to english.

It says that:
"Another user has already installed a decompressed version of the app. The actif user can not replace it with a packaged version."

What could I do to run the application when logged in with my account?